# How can I tell if I can power NFC chip passively?

Tags: microcontroller, nfc

I'm trying to figure out how to tell if I can power a particular NFC chip/microcontroller passively.  By passive I mean it needs no battery and can be powered by an NFC reader alone.

Many datasheets I read say they support ISO/IEC 14443 and all modes of NFC but don't clearly say anything about passive operation.  For example, [here is a chip from NXP](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/authentication/secure-authentication-microcontroller:A7005CAHN1).

Is there any way to tell if I can power it passively?

Is passive operation always possible for ISO/IEC 14443 contactless communication?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct NXP/Freescale chip?  The link you provide appears to be a micro processor. Not an NFC chip.

Comment: What do you mean by *passively* ? You mean you want to power it without communicating with it ?

Comment: The power to an NFC **tag or label** is transferred wirelessly, I would not call that "passive". The NFC tag/label chip is quite active once it is powered. That power comes from an NFC controller chip which of course needs external power, it can provide power to the tag/label but it cannot operate by wireless power. Such a controller chip would be in a phone or payment console.

Comment: Yes that it can be powered by a reader and communicate without a battery or other source of power

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *passively* you mean that there is no need to have a battery (or other supply means) on the tag/card side, then yes, ISO/IEC 14443 always implies that.

ISO/IEC 14443 describes a way to communicate wirelessly between the reader and the tag/card, but also the way to provide power to the tag/card. The card reader has to comply fully with it, meaning that it *must* have the ability to power the cards, and the cards should be able to use this power.

Note that this doesn't prevent the tag to eventually embed its own battery, if the prower provided by the reader (which is very small) is not enough. This may be the case for some car ignition key fobs that include a battery.

The A700x family of chips are a special kind of microcontrollers usually embedded in smart cards (but they can also be embedded in regular packages to be used on a PCB, eventually). For the models that support ISEO/IEC14443 (A7005 and A7006), these chips can be powered wirelessly, yes. You don't have to hook them to a battery.